# Finding Sum of Excel Column in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, excel, webforms

I'm new to working with Excel within Windows Forms Application using C#, but I'm trying to get the sum of column A from a CSV file chosen by the user with a button click and then put it within a textbox. However, I'm having trouble with getting the sum of the column.

This is what I have so far.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//Excel objects
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
string sFileName;
int iRow, iCol = 1;
double sum = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "CSV files | *.csv";
    dialog.Multiselect = false;
    if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        sFileName = dialog.FileName; 

        if(sFileName.Trim() != "")
        {
            ReadExcel(sFileName);
        }

        lblFileName.Text = sFileName;
    }
}
   
    
private void ReadExcel(string sFile)
{
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile);
    xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets["ExampleCSV"];
 
    Excel.Range xlRng = xlWorksheet.Range["A:A"];
   
    for (iRow = 1; iRow <= xlWorksheet.Rows.Count; iRow++)  // START FROM THE FIRST ROW.
    {
        if (xlWorksheet.Cells[iRow, 1].value == null)
        {
            break;      // BREAK LOOP.
        }
        else
        {
            sum += Double.Parse(xlWorksheet.Cells[iRow, 1].value);
            txtResults.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
    }

    xlWorkbook.Close();
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove your if else statement and replace it to this ternary logic:

```
string excelValue =  xlWorksheet.Cells[iRow, 1].value == null 
? "0" 
:  xlWorksheet.Cells[iRow, 1].value.ToString();
sum += Double.TryParse(excelValue, out _) 
? Convert.ToDouble(excelValue) 
: 0;
```

It's basically the same as an if else statement, but it is cleaner in many peoples opinion and it catches those nulls just as you were.

This method also catches alphas and other non-numerical characters and reverts those cells to 0 in the tryparse ternary logic which could be helpful in preventing other exceptions.

Refer to this to understand what 'break' does in a for loop.  It quits out of the loop entirely.
https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_break.php

Comment: I tried this and while I did not get any errors the application itself froze up when I selected a csv file.